# RewriteRule with Email Address

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a RewriteRule that can include an email address. I think something is wrong with my regular expression.

`RewriteRule ^user/verify/([a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ user.php?email=$1&token=$2 [L]`

Anyone have any thoughts?

Looking for this:

`http://www.example.com/user/user@email.com/sdfdsfa7dfs6dsfa6dsf8/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/verify/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ user.php?email=$1&token=$2 [L,NC]
```

This will capture everything between `user/verify/` and `sdfdsfa7dfs6dsfa6dsf8/` as email address.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious reason that comes to mind is that you're looking for

> www.example.com/**users**/user@email.com/sdfdsfa7dfs6dsfa6dsf8/

But your regex says

> ^**user/verify**/([a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$

But maybe that's just an error in your question?

---

As for the email address, there were already many many discussions on this topic: [regex+email](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+email). There could be email adresses not matching your regex, e.g. with a `+` (plus sign) in them.

Comment: @ATLChris, what about the `/verify`?